# Markdown to markdown but undo hard wraps

Tags: pandoc

Can pandoc be used to take a (pandoc) markdown file that is hard wrapped and reflow the text and use one line for paragraph, but otherwise don't change anything? Usecase would be to take hardwrapped text and transform it so an online textbox doesn't mess it up when pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a little in your definition of "doesn't change anything else", but `--wrap=none` is probably the option that you are after. Pandoc's Markdown output is opinionated, so it may not do exactly what you want.

Comment: You are right about the opinionated (you can't mix header styles for example), but that's something I can live with :)